# T-SQL Concatenation of GroupBy Output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would greatly appreciate any advice how to get second (desired) table basing on the GroupBy output provided in Actual Table.

[image]

Guess cursors will probably do a job but looking for simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL 2017 or SQL Azure you can use the `STRING_AGG` aggregate function with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Ticket, STRING_AGG  (PartNumber)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Ticket
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query

```
Create Table SepvalueTable (Ticket Int, PartNumber char(1))
Insert into SepvalueTable Values (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'),(2, 'C'),(3, 'A'),(3, 'B'),(3, 'C')

SELECT Ticket,
      PartNumber = 
              STUFF ( ( SELECT ' '+InrTab.PartNumber
                  FROM SepvalueTable InrTab
                  WHERE InrTab.Ticket = OutTab.Ticket
                  ORDER BY InrTab.Ticket
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE 
                  ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') 
                 , 1,1,SPACE(0))
FROM SepvalueTable OutTab
GROUP BY OutTab.Ticket;
```

The output is as shown below

```
Ticket  PartNumber
------------------
1       A B
2       C
3       A B C
```

You can find the full data live demo [**Live Demo Here**](https://rextester.com/ECIZX53257)